# Generate Upper and Lowercase Alphanumeric Random String in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How does one generate an upper and lowercase alphanumeric random string from oracle?

I have used `select DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('x', 10) from dual` to generate uppercase alphanumeric characters

and `select DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('a', 10) from dual` to generate uppercase and lowercase alpha characters

...but I'd like a function that does both upper and lower case, and alpha and numeric characters.

Also, bonus points (or just upvotes) if you can think of good reasons why Oracle didn't implement this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make your own function. This is one option:

```
create or replace function random_str(v_length number) return varchar2 is
    my_str varchar2(4000);
begin
    for i in 1..v_length loop
        my_str := my_str || dbms_random.string(
            case when dbms_random.value(0, 1) < 0.5 then 'l' else 'x' end, 1);
    end loop;
    return my_str;
end;
/

select random_str(30) from dual;

RANDOM_STR(30)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pAAHjlh49oZ2xuRqVatd0m1Pv8XuGs
```

You might want to adjust the `0.5` to take into account the different pool sizes - 26 for `l` vs. 36 for `x`. (`.419354839?`). You could also use value() and pass in the start and end range of the character values, but that would be character-set specific.

As to why... do Oracle need a reason? The use of `x` might suggest that it was originally hexadecimal and was expanded to include all upper-case, without it occurring to them to add a mixed-case version at the same time.

Comment: The number of calls to dbms_random would be reduced and the need to pick the threshold value in the case expression could be avoided by using this to get the next character to append: substr(
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
        mod(abs(dbms_random.random), 62)+1, 1)

Comment: @Janek I modified Alex's code to use your comment. Sadly I couldn't accept both your answers.

Answer (score 9):

Try this,

```
with
  r as (
    select
      level lvl,
      substr(
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
        mod(abs(dbms_random.random), 62)+1, 1) a
    from dual connect by level <= 10
  )
select
  replace(sys_connect_by_path(a, '/'), '/') random_string
from r
where lvl = 1
start with lvl = 10
connect by lvl + 1 = prior lvl
;
```

Output,

```
FOps2k0Pcy
```

Comment: My solution demonstrates that this can be done without PL/SQL but if I anticipated needing such a random string more than once I would use a PL/SQL function as in shown in @Alex Poole's answer.

Comment: I think this could also run afoul of SQL optimizations which might cause the random function to be called less than once per row.  See AskTom discussion at http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3181424400346795479.  Perhaps this could be prevented by seeding the random call with the level.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
select translate(dbms_random.string('a', 20), 'abcXYZ', '158249') from dual;
```

or, even MORE random ;)

```
select translate(dbms_random.string('a', 20), dbms_random.string('a',6), trunc(dbms_random.value(100000,999999))) from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_mac RETURN varchar2 IS
   w number :=0;
   a varchar2(10);
   b varchar2(50);
   x number :=0;
   y number :=0;
   z number :=0;
   c varchar2(50);
   result varchar2(20);
  BEGIN
  select round(dbms_random.value(1,99))into w from dual;
  SELECT upper(dbms_random.string('A', 2))into a FROM dual;
  SELECT round(dbms_random.value(1, 9)) into x FROM dual;
  SELECT upper(dbms_random.string('A', 4)) into b FROM dual;
  SELECT round(dbms_random.value(1, 9)) into y FROM dual;
  SELECT upper(dbms_random.string('A', 1)) into c FROM dual;
  SELECT round(dbms_random.value(1, 9)) into z FROM dual;
   result :=(  to_char(w) ||a|| to_char(x)|| b|| to_char(y)|| c ||to_char(z)) ;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Result ::' || result);
   RETURN result ;
  END fn_mac;
  /
```

Comment: upper(dbms_random.string('A', 2)) 
is same as 
dbms_random.string('U', 2)

Comment: opt seed values:
'a','A'  alpha characters only (mixed case)

'l','L'  lower case alpha characters only
'p','P'  any printable characters
'u','U'  upper case alpha characters only
'x','X'  any alpha-numeric characters (upper)

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the Printable option, then strip out any non-alphanumerics:

```
select SUBSTR(
         TRANSLATE(dbms_random.string('p',100)
            ,'A`~!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]\{}|;'':",./<>?'
            ,'A')
       ,1,10) from dual;
```

(Note: very rarely, this will return less than 10 characters)

or, map the offending characters to other letters and numbers (although this would reduce the randomness quite a bit):

```
select TRANSLATE(dbms_random.string('p',10)
            ,'A`~!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]\{}|;'':",./<>? '
            ,'A' || dbms_random.string('x',33)) from dual;
```

Great question, by the way.

Now, for my bonus points:

The reason Oracle didn't implement this is because no-one asked for it, and it probably is not a high priority.

Comment: Because Oracle are lazy then? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure r1
    is
    v_1 varchar2(1);
    v_2 varchar2(10);
    begin 
    for inner_c in 1..10
    loop
    select  substr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',mod(abs(dbms_random.random), 62)+1, 1) into v_1 from dual;
    v_2 := v_2 || v_1;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_2);
    end;
    /
```