# Generating a unique alphanumeric code for client, reducing collisions

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, kotlin, random, probability

I need to identify each booking with an easy code that can be given to the customer and used by them.

This code is *not* the "real" booking identifier.
That is, a booking already has a unique id which is used for Client <> Server communication - it is a Posgres auto-incremental int.

But we also want the customer to have a convenient short code, so they could use in case like:

1. reach out to our customer service with that code.
2. link their booking details into their mobile app.

So instead of having some 13-character long random sequence, we use 6-character long string of numbers + capital letters.

For example: `3RATW2`

My solution currently is:

1. take a charset of possible/allowed characters.
2. per each output character (6 times because the output should be 6 characters long):

   1. shuffle the charset with Fisher-Yates algorithm
   2. pick a random character from the result.

Using Kotlin code:

```
val charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ0123456789"
return (1..6)
    .map { // for each iteration :
         charset.toCharArray().shuffle() // shuffle (Fisher-Yates)
         .toString().random() // then take a random char
    }
    .joinToString("")
```

But since 6 is relatively low count, I'm not sure whether it's a good enough solution in order to avoid possible collisions as the number of bookings will be amounting. Is there a way to improve it (e.g. shuffling the charset more than once, etc.)?

Or is the only real solution to always get the list of existing booking codes from our DB (Postgres), and then the code generator will have to make sure the generated code is not included in that list (if included, run the code again until found a unique code)?

**UPDATE**

As @rossum suggested, I am trying to solve it with Feistel cipher. I was able to implement it for 5 chars, but for 6 I'm getting runtime OutOfBounds exception, maybe the "0x4f" in the encoding part is wrong(?) :

```
private val AllowedAlphabet = "23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"

fun encrypt30bit(value: Int): String {
    var l1 = (value shr 15) and 0x8FFF
    var r1 = value and 0x8FFF
    for (i in 0..2) {
        val key = ((((1366 * r1 + 150889) % 714025) / 714025.0) * 0x8FFF).toInt()
        val l2 = r1
        val r2 = l1 xor key
        l1 = l2
        r1 = r2
     }
     return encode6char((r1 shl 15) or l1)
}

private fun encode6char(number: Int): String {
     var num = number
     val chars = CharArray(6)
     repeat(6) { i ->
         chars[i] = AllowedAlphabet[num and 0x4f]
         num = num shr 6
     }
     return String(chars)
}
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem.  I'd guess that since collisions would be _really_ bad for the business, you need to make certain to avoid them.  Ways to do that include storing (and updating) the next ID in a global store such as a database (which needs atomic updates and everything to have access to it), or using a known-unique value such as combining a precise timestamp with a unique machine ID and process/thread ID and maybe hashing the result (which gives a very long ID).

Comment: We do have an ID for a booking , which is an auto-incremental int in Postgres, and is used for all of the Client<>Server communication.
But we just also want to give a customer a booking code which they can see and use to : (1) communicate with the support team, or (2) to link a booking to their mobile app. This code is a convenient ID for the user.
Maybe in this case it doesn't matter if there's already an existing booking code in the system? because the booking_id + user_id will be enough to distinguish the bookings ?

Comment: `AllowedAlphabet[num and 0x4f]` looks wrong, might be more obvious to use modulus operator instead, also shifting right by 6 looks wrong that would require 36 bit `Int`s which the they aren't.  Hence `AllowedAlphabet[num % AllowedAlphabet.length]` might be better and `num = num shr 5`. might just fix things.

Comment: @SamMason it doesn't crash now, but now I have a lot of collisions (~86% collisions)

Answer (score 2):

The way to avoid collisions when creating a new order would be to:

1. Generate a code for the new order
2. Check if there already is an order in the database with the same code (something like `SELECT 1 FROM orders WHERE code = "3RATW2"`)
3. Repeat until you generate a code that isn't already taken

I highly recommend adding a unique index on the column containing these codes so that it is absolutely impossible to create a collision in the DB.

If you generate 6 character codes with a charset of 36 characters you have 36^6 possible codes (~2 billion), you can increase this number by generating longer codes and/or including more possible characters.

Be aware that as you create more orders it will be more likely that you will create a collision when generating a new code and you will have to retry the generation (possibly multiple times)

Do orders that have been already processed still need to have a code? If not then you can remove the code from old/cancelled orders so that you can re-use the same code for a new order.

Comment: This is a good answer.  To build upon upon it, consider limiting the alphanumeric characters you offer to users, since users can mistake 1 for l etc.  So look at Crockford Base32 which reduces the number space but leaves you with less chance for user error.  Many implementations exist, his spec is here https://www.crockford.com/base32.html. Also consider that most users will type in lowercase so you should accept both lower/upper case variations

Answer (score 1):

Use an encryption. Encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and as long as you keep the same key and do not repeat a number the resulting encryption will not repeat. 0..9, A..Z gives 36 characters, though you might want to drop back to the Base32 character set to avoid ambiguities, such as 0,O or I,1.

Base32 is 5 bits per character, so 6 characters is 30 bits. You can use a 30 bit Feistel encryption, which you can write yourself easily enough provided you do not want cryptographic security.

Comment: that's very interesting, haven't heard of Feistel encryption. But since in the end the code will be only 6 characters, I'm assuming that theoretically there is some probability for collision. Now, since the real problem with randomly picking characters is not so much the theoretical prabability, but the "expected" one ("birthday paradox"), does it somewhat/greatly mitigate the problem or solves it entirely?  
thank you

Comment: See [Feistel Cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) for details. Since encryption is one-to-one, you are guaranteed no repeats as long as the inputs do not repeat. With 30 bits, you can have 2^30 unique inputs. Using 32 bits gives 2^32 unique inputs.

Comment: is there any java/kotlin (or other mainstream lang) where I can see an example how to implement it? without the cryptographic security part, as you mentioned

Comment: I found something similar for 5-characters (lower-case) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074677/how-to-generate-a-5-character-unique-alphanumeric-value-in-java/64076408#64076408

But I can't understand how to make it 6 characers, and upper case only.

Comment: That question uses 26 bits. You need to use 30 bits, so each half of the Feistel algorithm will be 15 bits, which makes the mask 0x8FFF.

Comment: almost there.. I just edited the post with my current implementation which doesn't work because of OutOfBoundsException.  I got to this implementation by editing the code that works for 5-long string, and then I used 15 bits and 0x8FFF masking, but maybe something else is wrong in the code ?

Comment: I think my example doesn't work because of the encoding part.. but i'm not sure, maybe the implementation itself is also wrong